# VB.NET - PetaPoco\NPoco - Fetch data from table with dynamic and static columns - Performance issue

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, petapoco, micro-orm, npoco

I have a specific situation to which I haven't found a solution yet.

I have several databases with the same structure where I have a table, (lets say `Users`), which has known columns such as: `UserID`, `UserName`, `UserMail`, etc...
In the same table, I have dynamic custom columns which I can know only on runtime, such as: `customField54`, `customField75`, `customField82`, etc...

I have a screen where I must show a list of users, and there are thousands of records (Must show **ALL** the users - no question about it).

The Users table columns in database A look like this:

```
| UserID | UserName | UserMail | customField54 | customField55 |
```

and for the example, lets say I have another database B, and the table Users there looks like this:

```
| UserID | UserName | UserMail | customField109 | customField211 | customField235 | customField302 |
```

I have a single code which each time connects to another database. So I have a single code - > multiple databases, while the difference in each database is the custom fields of the `Users` table.

If I work with a DataTable, I can query:

```
    SELECT * FROM Users
```

And then, dynamically I can retrieve the custom fields values, like this:

```
Dim customFieldsIDs() As Integer = GetCustomFieldsIDs()
Dim dt As DataTable = GetUserListData() // All users data in a DataTable

For Each dr In dt.Rows
    Response.Write(dr.Item("UserID"))
    Response.Write(dr.Item("UserName"))
    Response.Write(dr.Item("UserMail"))

    For Each cfID in customFieldsIDs
         Response.Write(dr.Item("customField" & cfID))
    Next 
Next
```

---

My intention is not to work with DataTables. I want to work with strong typed objects. I cannot create a POCO of Users with the customFields as is inside, because for each database the Users table has different customFields columns, so I can't create an object with strongly typed variables.

Then, I decided to create a class Users with the known columns inside, and also a dictionary holding the customFields.

In VB.NET, I created a class Users, which looks as follows:

```
Public Class User
    Public Property UserID As Integer
    Public Property UserName As Integer
    Public Property UserMail As Integer

    Public Property customFieldsDictionary As Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
End Class
```

The class has the static values: `UserID`, `UserName`, etc... 
Also, it has a dictionary of the `customFieldIDs` and their values, so I can retrieve the values in a single action (in O(1) complexity)

---

I use MicroORM PetaPoco\NPoco to populate the values.
The ORM allows me to fetch the Users data without me having to iterate the data by myself, by calling:

```
Dim userList As List(Of User) = db.Fetch(Of User)("SELECT * FROM Users")
```

But then the `customFields` dictionary is not populated.
In order to populate I have to iterate the `userList` and for each user retrieve the `customFields` data.
This is a very expensive way to fetch the data and results in a very bad performance.

**I'd like to know if there is a way to fetch the data into the User class using PetaPoco\NPoco with a single command and manage to populate the known values and the custom fields dictionary for every user without having to iterate through the whole collection.**

I hope it is understood. It is really difficult for me to explain and a very difficult issue to find a solution to.

Comment: NPoco V3 will have something like this. Checkout Test28(). https://github.com/schotime/NPoco/blob/dev3.0/src/NPoco.Tests/NewMapper/NestedConventionTests.cs#L512 Hopefully there will be an alpha this weekend

Comment: Could you explain how is the SQL command in the Test28 function supposed to work?

It looks like this:
"select 3 Id, 'Name' Name, null, 'dyn' Dynamic__Value1, 'dict' Dict__Value2". 

It is a bit strange to me. What does 'dict' Dict__Value2 stand for?
Please look at the database tables I showed in my original post.

Could you show me an example of how can the Test28 functionality can be achieved using my database?

Answer (score 2):

You could try fetching everything into a dictionary and then you could map specific keys/values to your User object properties.

EDIT:

I'm not using VB.NET anymore, but I'll try to explain.

Create the indexer similar to this one: 
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/VB/0120__Class-Module/DefineIndexerforyourownclass.htm

In the indexer you would do something like:

```
if (index == "FirsName") then
  me.FirstName = value
end if

....

if (index.startWith("customField") then
  var indexValue = int.Parse(index.Replace("customField",""))
  me.customFieldsDictionary[indexValue]  = value
end if
```

NPoco supports materializing the data into dictionary:

```
var users = db.Fetch<Dictionary<string, object>>("select * from users");
```

You should be able to pass your class to the NPoco and force it to use the Fetch overload for dictionary.

I've used this approach before, but I can't find the source at the moment.

Comment: Yes indeed, you can look at the first example in my post and see that's what I did. But then it would force me to iterate through each and every user and copy the wanted properties, causing a performance decrease.

I wanted to fetch the whole data on the Fetch command in the right format

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that.How about implementing IDictionary interface on the User object and setting the properties' values in the indexer?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your suggestion. Do you mind showing an example of what you mean?

Comment: I'm not VB.NET expert, but I'll try to explain.